# SQL query to find students who received an A for every course taken

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following schema:

Students(sid, firstname, lastname, status, gpa, email)

Courses(dept_code, course#, title)

Classes(classid, dept_code, course#, sect#, year, semester, limit, class_size)

Enrollments(sid, classid, lgrade)

I need some help to find out all the students who received an A for every course taken.

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: is `lgrade` constrained to non-null values? Also, what are the possible grades? (For example, are there A+, A, A- and if there are, what do you really need - "all grades are A", or "all grades are no less than A", or "no less than A-"?)

Comment: why is this homework being answered, but the student has done nothing?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select * from students 
where sid not in (select distinct sid from enrollement where coalesce (lgrade,'X') <> 'A')
```

It means: take all students where none of his/her grade is other than A
if you wanna to get also the name of the class and course, you have to join also both tables

Comment: This will return students who have no grades at all.  That *technically* meets the requirement "who received an A for every course taken", but I would guess it is not what the OP intends.

Comment: I changed it to not take  lgrade null

Comment: "is not in" will cause a syntax error. "ISNULL" will cause another one. Perhaps this is not Oracle SQL? In any case, the OP tagged this as Oracle from the very beginning, so this is a -1 from me.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - perhaps you are right, but that would be disappointing. A student who has taken no classes at all is, indeed, one who has gotten an A "in all courses taken." I know laypeople may have a problem with that, but people who work with relational databases should be much more comfortable with elementary set theory than "laypeople."

Comment: I edited it again, "coalesce" is supported by oracle, and the extra misstyped "is" is removed

Answer (score 1):

I might suggest doing this with an aggregation:

```
select e.sid
from enrollement e
group by e.sid
having min(lgrade) = max(lgrade) and min(lgrade) = 'A';
```

Comment: Loved the solution 

Answer (score 0):

Try not to overthink this:

```
SELECT s.*
  FROM STUDENTS s
  WHERE s.GPA = 4.0
```

That'll work for the A=4, B=3, C=2, D=1, F=0 case (standard American grading system).

For non-standard systems (such as my kids high school where A=5 for honors and advanced placement classes) we can't trust the GPA:

```
SELECT s.*
  FROM STUDENTS s
  INNER JOIN (SELECT SID, COUNT(*) AS CLASS_COUNT
                FROM ENROLLMENTS
                GROUP BY SID) cc
  INNER JOIN (SELECT SID, COUNT(*) AS A_GRADE_COUNT
                FROM ENROLLMENTS
                WHERE LGRADE = 'A'
                GROUP BY SID) ag
    ON ag.SID = s.SID
  WHERE CLASS_COUNT = A_GRADE_COUNT
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the clearest:

```
select e.sid
from enrollement e
group by e.sid
having count(case when lgrade = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) = count(*) and count(*) > 0
```